# How can I get a ndarray which contains the different ways of adding up to N a certain number of elements?

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, python-itertools

For example, suppose I have a chain of 3 elements (natural numbers) and I fix `N=2`. What I want is to find, in form of a matrix or 2D-array, the different ways of arrange such elements so they add up to 2.
In this case, we'd have:

```
[
[0,0,2],
[0,2,0],
[2,0,0],
[0,1,1],
[1,1,0],
[1,0,1]
]
```

Note that each row (of length 3) sum 2.
I want to generalize this behavior to the case of arbitrary number of elements and N.

I'm wondering if there exists an efficient way to implement this algorithm in python

Comment: You've posed a problem, not an algorithm.  I doubt if `numpy` will help.  Just collect the combinations you find in a list.

Comment: @hpaulj And how can I go for that, is it possible with itertools module or something related?

Comment: Start small and work up.  Don't focus on special tools.  You sould be able to do this with normal iterations.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def ways_of_adding_up_to_n(number, elements, stack = []):
    if elements == 2:
        result = [[i, number - i] for i in range(number + 1)]
        if stack != []:
            result = [stack + result[i] for i in range(len(result))]
        return result
    else:
        result = []
        for i in range(number + 1):
            result.extend(ways_of_adding_up_to_n(number - i, elements - 1, stack + [i]))
        return result

print(ways_of_adding_up_to_n(2, 3))
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, please consider adding an explanation on what it does and how it solves the OP's problem